# Ошибка в tkinter python 3 связанная с bind и самовызыванием функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Суть в чём: использую python 3 с tkinter. Есть функция, которая вызывает сама себя через `after()`. После первого вызывания прерывается и выходит ошибка (вызываю через `s` на клавиатуре и метод `bind`). Вот проблемный фрагмент (попытаюсь все импорты, что тут используются и другие команды впихнуть, если что-то забуду - не обессудьте) кода:

```
form tkinter import *

def stopwatch(event):
    global test, after_id, milisec, sec, min, hour, x, y, z

    if sec > 59:
        sec = 0
        min += 1

    if min>59:
        min = 0
        hour += 1

    if hour>23:
        sec = 0
        min = 0
        hour = 0

    if sec < 10:
        x = '0'+str(sec)
    else:
        x = str(sec)

    if min < 10:
        y = '0'+str(min)
    else:
        y = str(min)

    if hour < 10:
        z = '0'+str(hour)
    else:
        z = str(hour)

    after_id = window.after(1000, stopwatch)
    label1.configure(text=str(z+':'+y+':'+x))

window = Tk()

window.bind("<s>",stopwatch)

label1 = Label(window, text='')
label1.config(font=('Ubuntu',20)
label1.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

а вот, собственно, ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 745, in callit
    func(*args)
TypeError: stopwatch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'


 Что делать?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def stopwatch(event=None):
```

Но кроме этого, в коде множество недостатков - опечатки, нарушение PEP8, использование глобальных переменных, перекрытие стандартных имён. И несмотря на то, что приведён код не полностью, и часть программной логики скрыта, есть основания подозревать, что и она ошибочна.